# DHCP server on access point seems to block any access to the internet

Tags: networking, router, dns, dhcp

I am trying to build the following network:

```
ADSL Modem > Various Machines (Wireless and Wired)
            > Switch > Wifi Access Point with DHCP Server > Various machines connected by WIFI
                     > Various Machines (wired)
```

I have switched off the DHCP server on the modem so it should be working only as the internet gateway.  From my cable modem machines machines connected by both wires and wireless one of which leads to a switch that has a TPLINK Access Point that I am running the DHCP server on.

The reason that I am doing is that the modem's DHCP server does not work very well.  When I use it there are a number of machines on the network that are not discoverable - such as NATs and Network Audio Players.

When I use the TPLINK Access Point as the DHCP server all machines are discoverable but then none of them can connect to the internet.  I have tried to set the DNS IP on the DHCP server to either the AP or the modem but it does not work.  All machines are able to ping the model so they know that it exists.  But - when I try to ping or trace route anything on the internet it is blocked.

I have tried to debug using Wireshark but I am not sure what to look for.  Can anyone suggest what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the DHCP server TPLINK does not provide the correct default gateway. If you did not explicitly tell the TPLINK to use the modem as default gateway, the TPLINK will probably use it's own WAN interface, which should not be connected in your set-up.

Setting the default gateway on the DHCP server of the TPLINK should provide Internet access.

If not, check the default gateway on the systems. Is it the modem? If not, try to renew the DHCP-lease. Did that help? If not, try to set the default gateway on one system to the modem. Does it work then?

Comment: Yup - it was the default gateway.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Without more detailed information about your setup my best guess is:

Most likely the DHCP server on the access-point serves the access-points own ip-address as default gateweay to your clients.
But the ADSL modem is the real default gateway.

Second potential problem is DNS. You will want the AP to also act as DNS for your local clients, but you must ensure the AP itself uses your ISP DNS (or Google, or Cloudflare, or OpenDNS) as upstream DNS.

Third potential problem: Depending of firmware of the AP it is possible the AP only provides DHCP and DNS services to clients talking to its Wifi and wired downstream and will NOT do that for the clients connected directly to the ADSL modem and the switch (aka upstream from the AP).

Comment: I think 1) is the real issue – OP forgot to change the advertised gateway in DHCP settings... DNS shouldn't be a problem (there is no reason why it needs to be provided by the AP). And if it's configured as a plain AP (bridge) then it shouldn't even have a distinction between upstream and downstream.

Comment: @user1686 Poster already mentioned the ADSL modem has issues with name-resolving for local clients which the AP doesn't have. That is local DNS related. Hence my advice to use the DNS of the AP toward the clients.

Comment: It was the default gateway.  But the DNS confuses me.  On the modem the DNS is set to the external DNS IPs which is fine.  But on the DHCP is it better to set the internal DNS IPs to the DHCP server, the modem, the external IPs or it doesn't matter>

Comment: @sibruce If the AP runs its own DNS I would prefer that to be used by all clients. Just have the AP forward  any non-local DNS query to the external DNS. (Because the DHCP in the AP will most likely update the AP's DNS to have the names/ip-addresses of all DHCP connected clients which makes client to client name-resolving a lot easier.)

Comment: Thanks @Tonny for your help!